# Create Slack bot without Workspace integration

Tags: bots, slack, slack-api

Is there a way to create a Script that listens to any new message in a Slack Workspace, without having to be installed by the Workspace Admin and without being visible to other users in the Workspace?
It seems that official Slack Apps need to be installed into a Workspace, but I'd like to quietly listen (using my login credentials of course).

What I'm looking to build is a personal "Slack bot" that evaluates each new message in a given Workspace and tells me if it's relevant for me. Otherwise I can ignore.

Is this possible in any way (maybe also without the official Slack API)...?

Thanks a lot for any hints!!

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to use the Slack API on a given workspace if you were not given access to this workspace by an admin. Unlike other services such as GitHub where you can act as a user, without having an application per se, Slack requires an app installation.